# Accessing an iFrame's dom from a Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, firefox-addon

I've spent a long time trying different things to get this to work but nothing does and documentation is not helping much.

I'm trying to populate a form inside an iframe that I dynamically inject into a page. To inject that iframe I do:

```
myObject.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
myObject.iframe.setAttribute("src", data.url);
myObject.iframe.setAttribute("id","extension-iframe");
myObject.window.document.getElementById('publisher').appendChild(myObject.iframe);
myObject.iframe.addEventListener("load", function(){
    myObject.populate(data);
}, false);
```

which works fine and DOES trigger the populate() method. My problem is getting the document or window objects for that iframe. I've tried all of the following:

```
myObject.iframe.window
myObject.iframe.document
myObject.iframe.content
```

but these are all undefined.

I also tried passing the event object to that iframe's load event listener and then doing:

```
event.originalTarget
```

But that didn't work either.

I am reading the following documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

But either I'm not understanding it or it's just not properly explained.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `myObject.iframe.contentDocument`

Something along the lines of this:

```
// For accessing browser window from sidebar code.
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                   .rootTreeItem
                   .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                   .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

var gBrowser = mainWindow.gBrowser;

var iframes = gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            for (var i=0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
                var check_elem = iframes[i].contentDocument.getElementById('myid');
                if (check_elem) {
                    ...;
                }
            }
```

Comment: That may work for the browser, but what about XUL iframes? I can confirm Lukasz Salamon's answer is working for XUL.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/contentWindow) property?

```
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Comment: I did but still cannot access the window. Check this out for a more complete explanation: http://gist.github.com/242927

And thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I got nothing else then sorry, not familiar with XUL.

Comment: contentWindow is not available on load, in XUL. Ironically, if you use JS debugger, it DOES work, because you're stepping through much later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm passing in the event object and then `event.originalTarget` (like you mentioned) and it's working fine. Although I had to set `useCapture` parameter of addEventListener to true in order to get my event called.

So if I understand correctly you need to access document in populate method...

I would pass `event.originalTarget` as a parameter to your method 
or 
in load event I would set for example `myObject.document` property and then use it in populate method.

```
myObject.iframe.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    var doc = event.originalTarget;
    myObject.populate(data,doc);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost had the same problem. Using the following code gets me the iframe (Firebug is used for debugging):

```
iframes = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  var elmInput = iframes[i];
  Firebug.Console.log(elmInput);
}
```